# Mobile keyboard does not focus text field - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, focus, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm really lost on this one. This is my code:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols='12'>
                <v-text-field
                    label="This is a label"
                    single-line
                    solo
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

If I enter text into the field on desktop it's fine. Even viewing the browser through Chrome DevTools and using the PC keyboard works. But direct entry using the phone's keyboard does not. The text just gets overlayed on the label.

[image]

What's more interesting is that it focuses properly if you type a space or punctuation and then the letters.

[image]

And yes, that's all the code I have in the file haven't even added in `export defaults` yet

Using `nuxt v2.12.2` and `@nuxtjs/vuetify v1.11.2`

EDIT: I've opened a [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/320). If it doesn't get answered here you can always check the issue.

Comment: Second that. I'll expand saying that it's not focusing issue, the element gains focus just fine, but somehow doesn't handle input events on mobile device - if counter is present, it'll also stay at 0 till eg space key pressed. Switching focus to other element triggers textfield/textarea to handle the input too.

Comment: Related issue at github: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11201
Should've been solved with latest update of vuetify, but using @2.2.26 and still experiencing same problem. Issue might be specific to my phone (Blackberry Key2), since it has custom keyboard soft.

Comment: @ego that issue is for the actual vuetify module not the nuxt-community one. I don't know if when vuetify gets updated, nuxt-vuetify also gets updated? I always thought they were two separate things

Comment: @ego probably not, my iOS and Android users complained

Comment: Updating keyboard soft on my phone (installing/updating Google Keyboard at playstore) fixed the problem for me... Try it, if it works - as a temp-fix might put a notification asking users to update the keyboard app (till package fixes issue). Or better ux, but hacky solution - if you don't have too many inputs, might do ref.blur(), nexttick and ref.focus() with some interval - like 300ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem is due to vuetify version - v2.2.22 is the last one that is working properly. For now try downgrading your packages as per instructions in here (try experimenting with different package versions): https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-update-vuetify-to-latest-version-in-nuxt-js/66326